# Fill NA with data from another DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have calculated the mean of 'LotFrontage" grouped by 'Neighborhood' into a DF called LotFrontage_mean. It looks like this

```
   Neighborhood  LotFrontage
0       Blmngtn    47.142857
1       Blueste    24.000000
2        BrDale    21.562500
3       BrkSide    57.509804
4       ClearCr    83.461538
5       CollgCr    71.682540
6       Crawfor    71.804878
7       Edwards    68.217391
8       Gilbert    79.877551
9        IDOTRR    62.500000
10      MeadowV    27.800000
11      Mitchel    70.083333
```

In my original DF, I want to fill in the NA's in the 'LotFrontage' with the mean of the LotFrontage from its respective neighborhood. For example I want all the NA's for the Neighborhood Blmngtn, in the LotFrontage column to be 47.142857.

This is what I have tried

```
house_df['LotFrontage'] = house_df[['Neighborhood','LotFrontage']].apply(lambda x: x['LotFrontage'] if x['LotFrontage'].notnull() else LotFrontage_mean.at(x['Neighborhood']))
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you your helper `LotFrontage_mean` is not necessary, you can replace `NaN` in `apply` or `transform` by custom function:

```
house_df['LotFrontage'] = house_df.groupby('Neighborhood')['LotFrontage']
                                  .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Or:

```
house_df['LotFrontage'] = house_df.groupby('Neighborhood')['LotFrontage']
                                  .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

If this solutions cannot be used use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mapped = house_df['Neighborhood'].map(LotFrontage)
house_df['LotFrontage'] = house_df['LotFrontage'].combine_first(mapped)
```

Sample:

```
n = ['Blmngtn', 'Blueste', 'BrDale', 'BrkSide', 'ClearCr', 'CollgCr']
a = [0.1,0.2,0.3,np.nan]

N = 100
house_df = pd.DataFrame({'Neighborhood': np.random.choice(n, size=N),
                         'LotFrontage':np.random.choice(a, size=N)}, 
                          columns=['Neighborhood','LotFrontage'])

print (house_df.head(10))
  Neighborhood  LotFrontage
0      BrkSide          0.1
1      CollgCr          NaN
2      BrkSide          NaN
3      Blueste          0.3
4       BrDale          NaN
5      ClearCr          0.3
6       BrDale          0.1
7      ClearCr          0.2
8      CollgCr          NaN
9      ClearCr          0.1

LotFrontage = house_df.groupby('Neighborhood')['LotFrontage'].mean()
print (LotFrontage)
Neighborhood
Blmngtn    0.200000
Blueste    0.221429
BrDale     0.180000
BrkSide    0.193333
ClearCr    0.223529
CollgCr    0.208333
Name: LotFrontage, dtype: float64
```

---

```
house_df['LotFrontage'] = house_df.groupby('Neighborhood')['LotFrontage'] \
                                  .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

print (house_df.head(10))
  Neighborhood  LotFrontage
0      BrkSide     0.100000
1      CollgCr     0.208333
2      BrkSide     0.193333
3      Blueste     0.300000
4       BrDale     0.180000
5      ClearCr     0.300000
6       BrDale     0.100000
7      ClearCr     0.200000
8      CollgCr     0.208333
9      ClearCr     0.100000
```

---

```
mapped = house_df['Neighborhood'].map(LotFrontage)
house_df['LotFrontage'] = house_df['LotFrontage'].combine_first(mapped)
print (house_df.head(10))

  Neighborhood  LotFrontage
0      BrkSide     0.100000
1      CollgCr     0.208333
2      BrkSide     0.193333
3      Blueste     0.300000
4       BrDale     0.180000
5      ClearCr     0.300000
6       BrDale     0.100000
7      ClearCr     0.200000
8      CollgCr     0.208333
9      ClearCr     0.100000
```